# withTransaction and saving a lot of objects?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm

In the controller method is the following chunk of code.

```
def stat = ''

    stat = assignBibNumbers(compositeEvent.id)
```

Here is the private function called in the above code: Please note that only the relevant part is shown

```
private def assignBibNumbers(Long id){

    ...

    def eventRange = bibsService.convertRangeStringToRangeList(compositeEvent.bibsRange)


    for(int j=0; j<finRegsList.size(); j++){

        finRegsList[j].raceParticipant.bibNumber = eventRange[j]
        finRegsList[j].save()


    }


        return "Bib Setup Complete! No bib assignment was made."




}
```

The save doesnt work in the above case. THe bib numbers are not assigned.

Now if i change the above first part of the code to

```
def stat = ''
RaceRegistration.withTransaction { status ->
    stat = assignBibNumbers(compositeEvent.id)
}
```

it works! So i am very confused why i should wrap the function in a withTransaction block. I thought even without wrapping in in transaction block the save should still work. What is causing the save() to not work without a transaction block? Should saves in a loop always be wrapped in a transaction block? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought even without wrapping in in transaction block the save should still work.

This is true if your method is annotated with `@Transactional`, or the class. In your case, try annotating `assignBibNumbers()`, like so

```
@Transactional
private def assignBibNumbers(Long id){...}
```